# undeclared identifier posix_fallocate() and fallocate() in macOS, clang 12.00

Tags: c++, macos, clang, fallocate

I tried using the `fallocate()` or the `posix_fallocate()` function in my CPP program, but my compiler kept telling me, that it couldn't find that function. So I created this minimal program:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
int main() {
    int fd = open("lol", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (fd < 0) return 1;
    return posix_fallocate(fd, 0, 400000);
}
```

But when I'm trying to compile it, my compiler tells me:

```
c++ -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++2a    test.cc   -o test
test.cc:5:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'posix_fallocate'
    return posix_fallocate(fd, 0, 400000);
           ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

As you can see, I'm using c++20. I tried this on my Mac with Catalina and clang. It works fine on a Linux shell that I tried.

Why is that and is there a way to make `fallocate()` work on a Mac?

Comment: Did you define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to a proper value? Must be `>=200112L`.

Comment: `getpagesize()` returns 4096, so 400000 should be plenty enough, shouldn't it?